# Secure switch for network monitorring

Tags: networking, switch, security

I'm looking for a switch with port mirroring function and write protection function for his flash memory, so that no malicious code can be stored at the chipset or other connected machines can change configurations during runtime. Does anyone please give me some product recommendations with respect to the requirements above?